# RewriteRule is working, but not html tags

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this kind of site which is url-ed now:

```
127.0.0.1/mysite/User/username
```

Here is the .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewritRule ^User/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

it is working, but the problem is the pictures, the form is not working. How can I solve that?

Update:

path of pictures:

```
/mysite/photos/profile/picture.png
```

I think i know the problem but i do not know yet how to solve it:

problem:

even though `127.0.0.1/mysite.com/User/username` is ok

my page is treating it like this: `127.0.0.1/mysite.com/users.php/?user=username`

see the `/` after `.php` ? that is the reason I think why my `html tags` are not working.

So can you give me some suggestion of how to do it ?

Summary:

```
mysite.com/User/username
```

is treated as

```
mysite.com/users.php/?user=username
```

the `slash (/)` is the problem.

For people who encounters the same problem as me, here is how mysite works:

my img src : `photos/profile/photo.jpeg`
changed it into

```
/root/photos/profile/photo.jpeg
```

just add your main or root directory. hope it can help anyone.

Added question:

i have a site on my `localhost` like this: `127.0.0.1/rootfoldername/page.php`

but i want to visit my site with no *rootfoldername* on it. like this: `127.0.0.1/page.php`

how can I do this ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what's not working?

Comment: the pictures is not showing, the form too is not working. it works before i make an .htaccess.

Comment: Any chance the pictures are in `/mysite/User/username/picture.png`?

Comment: no it is in different folder `/mysite/photos/profile/picture.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put rewrite condition.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewritRule ^User/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) users.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

This skips or stops if file exists.

Comment: before or after the rule ?

Comment: Just after RewriteEngine On. ,, before RewriteRule

Comment: I can show the profile of the user, the only problem is the `image` and the `form`

Comment: Sorry, there was slight mistake in rewrite cond, now fixed it. Please try my script again.

Comment: sorry, it is not working too, can you review my question I updated. thanks

Comment: / shouldn't make a problem. Can u reassure that there is !-f & !-d instead of just -f & -d in rewrite cond??

Comment: yup , triple checked it

Comment: so, the problem was with img src after all

Comment: yup, links must start from the root directory down to the file